# Error when imputing low-variance observations with mice

Tags: r, random-forest, r-mice

I'm working with a few datasets that have missing values, which should be predictable based on other complete observations in the datasets. I would like to impute these using multiple imputation with the mice package. Many of the data values are very small (E-3 or -4).

The behavior of mice has been a bit odd. When there are observations with many values of low variance, say, ~300 observations of roughly 50 variables, I receive errors using the "rf" or "midastouch" methods. The other methods work fine. If I increase the variance of the observations the errors disappear.

```
library(mice)

#simulate the dataset
sim <- matrix(data = rnorm(14500, sd=0.01), nrow=290)

#randomly select 20% of rows to have some missing data to replicate the pattern of NAs in the real datasets
r <- sample(1:nrow(sim), nrow(sim)*0.2)

#for each selected row, randomly set 6 of the 50 variables to NA.
for(i in r){
  sim[i, sample(50, 6)] <- NA
}

mice(sim, method='rf')
```

This returns:

```
Error in randomForest.default(x = xobs, y = yobs, ntree = 1, ...) : 
  NAs in foreign function call (arg 11)
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In randomForest.default(x = xobs, y = yobs, ntree = 1, ...) :
  invalid mtry: reset to within valid range
2: In max(ncat) : no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf
3: In randomForest.default(x = xobs, y = yobs, ntree = 1, ...) :
  NAs introduced by coercion to integer range
```

And using `mice(sim, method='midastouch')`:

```
Error in base::rbind(...) : 
  number of columns of matrices must match (see arg 2)
```

If we use a different method, or increase the variance of the observations, no problem:

```
mice(sim, method='norm')

sim <- sim*10
mice(sim, method='rf')
mice(sim, method='midastouch')
```

I initially thought that the low variance must cause an issue with randomForest, yet 'midastouch' also fails, albeit with a different error. I've tried searching the issue, debugging in R, and searching through the mice and randomForest code, but I can't figure out why these errors might occur. Any help would be appreciated.

I'm performing multiple imputation.

Comment: Try `res <- missForest::missForest(sim); res$ximp`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! missForest works (and is very cool), but I was hoping to use mice for its focus on implementing "proper" multiple imputation, according to Rubin (1987, 1996). This is detailed in Ch. 2 of van Buuren's (the author of mice) text, Flexible Imputation of Missing Data. His implementation of rf for imputation is more like predictive mean matching, where a 'donor' value is not predicted by rf per se, but is randomly drawn from the terminal nodes of the forest.

EDIT: The idea is to select only values that were observed, but also to introduce variability in the predictions.

Comment: I know Rubin for sure. However, time marches on and methods may evolve. Have you read e.g. [Bertismas et al. 2018](https://jmlr.org/papers/volume18/17-073/17-073.pdf) and [Penone et al. 2014](https://besjournals.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/full/10.1111/2041-210X.12232)?

Comment: Thanks for those refs. I really enjoyed Bertismas et al. Interesting, though, that they still use mice for their version of multiple imputation ('opt.mi') to produce variable "warm starts". Penone et al actually found that missForest produced elevated bias in the imputed values for some of their trials, which is what we're attempting to avoid using the multiple imputations rather than a "prediction".